# Anylogic deterministic parameter variation

Tags: parameters, anylogic

Best wishes for the new year. I have a question about the parameter variation. Using a python script I generate multiple solutions to be evaluated via simulation. The main variable is called individual and I would like the simulation to be performed for a specific range say 1-10 where I retrieve the simulation results for each value in this range. However, when I export the results to excel there exists some randomisation i.e. not all individual values are exported but for example individuals 0, 10, 5, 4, 1. I assume this is due to the seed value. Is there a seed value that can be used to simulate each individual value in a range following the normal order so 1,2,3 .... 10? Or is there another solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you setup your ParamVar-experiment correctly. Independent of any random seed, replications, etc... If your setup looks as below, the ParamVar will run the model with all 10 values:
[image]

So it is either your setup that is wrong, or your outputs. I suggest you start with a simple trial without any Python parsing to see if normal setups work. Find the root cause (it is not the replications setting)

NOTE: If you run with "fixed seed", the model will be run 10 times with the same seed but a different value for `myParam`.

NOTE ALSO: The *sequence* of runs can appear random when you allow parallel evaluations: you cannot determine which is started first and which ends first. Switch off parallel evaluations and things are started and finished in sequence:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If the user selects, min-max-step option, the model does run enough number of times to cover all the values.

Yes, it is due to the random seeds used in the simulation. You need to make sure that you do enough replications so that all values are covered. If you have a parameter in the range of 1-10 with increment 1, then, running 10 replications cannot guarantee you that all the values will be used. Increase the number of iterations to guarantee that all values are covered.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the answer.

Comment: Hi @Yashar, pretty sure this answer is not correct, tbh. If you setup the ParamVar to vary between 1-10 in steps of 1, it will do that 100% independent of random seeds and replications

Comment: yep, this answer is definitely incorrect

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin and @Felipe! Correcting my answer.